# Tailwind CSS: edit the dark mode variant of a class using plain css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need some help please, I'm using Tailwind CSS along with a CSS file where I have these classes

```css
.hamburgerTop,
.hamburgerMiddle,
.hamburgerBottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

I would like to change the background to #fff when the theme is set to dark, how can I target the :dark pseudo in CSS?

Answer (score 5):

`:dark` is not a pseudo selector, it is a Tailwind-made "variant".

In your CSS, if you want to use the user's preferred setting (which is what Tailwind does by default), implement the [`prefers-color-scheme` media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme):

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .hamburgerTop,
    .hamburgerMiddle,
    .hamburgerBottom {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

If however, you've configured Tailwind to [use the class strategy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) and you're manually toggling a `.dark` (or similar) class, it'd be something like:

```
.dark .hamburgerTop,
.dark .hamburgerMiddle,
.dark .hamburgerBottom {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Neither option really has anything to do with Tailwind, other than you matching its strategy in your own CSS.

If it were me, I'd simply use the Tailiwind utility classes:

```
<div class="hamburgerTop absolute top-0 left-0 w-6 h-0.5 bg-black dark:bg-white"></div>
<!-- ... ->
```

But perhaps you have your own reasons not to.

Comment: I'm using the class strategy indeed and I've already tried the ".dark . hamburger { ... }" approach and it doesn't work.

Comment: As for creating the span elements using tailwind utility classes, this approach is not suited for my case since there are many other classes and animation involved in different states.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hamburgerTop,
.hamburgerMiddle,
.hamburgerBottom {
  @apply dark:bg-white
}
```

You can use @apply to add tailwind classes to the css, and dark: to only target dark mode.